# Integrating Identity Server 3 Openid Connect with CMS applications like Dotnetnuke (DNN)

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, openid-connect, thinktecture-ident-server

I want to add Identity Server 3 v.2 to my DNN (Dotnetnuke) CMS portal so that I can have both external clients (native mobile, javascript SPA, native destkop)
my DNN Web application, access WebAPI hosted in my DNN Web application.

DNN has many extensibility points, the most important being a module which is of these types: Webforms, MVC or SPA.
DNN has its own user, roles store and permissions. Permissions to  actions in DNN web site like "view" and "edit"  modules  are assigned to roles.

Permissions in DNN can be assigned to pages (which is the container of page modules), modules (can inherit permissions from the containing page or have their own) and to files and folders that are uploaded to DNN Web application.

DNN has its own login screen for local user store and can have external login providers such as Facebook, Google etc. through DNN's authentication provider extensibility.

I need to figure out how to integrate Identity Server with its:
- Authorize Endpoint
-Token Endpoint
-UserInfo Endpoint

IdentityServer.Samples has these clients:

- Code Flow Client Demo
- Implicit Client Demo
- Hybrid Native Client Demo
- Katana Hybrid Client Demo
- Client Credentials Flow Client
- Client Credentials Flow Client with Client Certificate
- Custom Grant Client
- Resource Owner Flow Client

**Which one of these clients are the best to use to integrate with DNN given my requirements? More then one?**

DNN already has support for these providers:

- Facebook,
- Google,
- Live Authentication,
- Twitter and
- Library for DNN OAuth Server Support

**I would like to know if Identity Server belong to this list or does even more?**

**How would I go about preserving DNN login page and still use Identity Server Endpoints?**

**Will I need to add Identity Server as yet another Authentication provider?**

I would probably like to suppress consent screen for users accessing DNN WebApi using DNN Web application directly (with all types of modules),
and use Identity Server's Endpoints from Native Windows and Mobile as well as clients coming from third party web sites or clients.

**Is there any Identity Server 3 integration with other open source CMS applications, like Orchard, Umbraco, Kentico etc.**

**I would appreciate if someone will outline steps and pseudo examples on how to achieve this integration.**

Thanks,
Rad

Comment: did you get a solution for your question? we are looking to use OpenID with DNN9, and unable to find a readymade provider. their documentation states that DNN Core has OpenID support, but I am unable to find how to activate this module.

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/manifest-authenticationsystem-component

Comment: There still isn't anything available for OpenIdConnect, that's why I've written an oidc provider and client for DNN. It's basically a POC, using IdentityServer4 to log in (using authorization_code), but anyone who is interested can use it as a starting point: https://github.com/Ruard/ProcsIT.Dnn.OpenIdConnect